# How to disable password reset by users on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, passwords, password-policy

Is there a way to disable the password reset done by users on MySQL, except the root user? Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The user is the owner of the password. Thhis disabling makes no sense, especially while taking into account that the root user can change the password or disable the account at any moment.

Comment: From the other side you may investigate the effect of enabling [read_only system variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_only).